# Will Rails db Data be Lost on Redeploy to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, deployment

I've been searching and doing my research but I can't seem to find any articles directly talking about this. I have an art gallery rails app with around 6 models of different attributes, pieces of art, etc. When I make changes to their site and redeploy, will the databases also be reset? Or is Postgres and the rails app separate on Heroku?

I also read that someone takes all of their data and puts it into `seed.rb` then repopulates the databases with the seed data once it's redeployed? Does that sound right? Any insight would be very helpful. Thank you

Comment: Using ```seed.rb``` is good for small amounts of default data (I use it to load the countries in the ISO 3166 list). I would take care that you do the equivalent of an ```UPSERT``` anytime you are seeding, you want to be able to run the seed file multiple times without creating duplicates. You can use ```first_or_create``` with Rails 3.2.1+

Answer (score 4):

If you're using a database, your data won't get lost on redeploys. Only the data which is stored in `/tmp` gets lost after a deploy is performed.

I'm going to assume you're using heroku postgres. In this case check out this, it's good to regularly create backups: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups

In `seed.rb` you should only add data which is necessary to set up the project, and nothing more. e.g. create an admin.

Answer (score 3):

No data will be lost on redeploy to heroku until you intentionally do so.
Seed data only for populating some default database values in a rails application.

I am assuming you are uploading pictures in your application and they don't persist after deploy. So that true. Heroku does allow you to upload images to heroku. But they not persist after deployment.

Uploaded images persist for particular interval of time.

If this is the case with you try upload images to amazon s3 bucket, all uploading gem support that.